# Chosen dropdown : make search_contains true for all dropdown at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

WHile initialisation of three dropdowns i have used this script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#drp_menu').chosen({ search_contains: true });  
    $('#drp_menu2').chosen({ search_contains: true });      
    $('#drp_menu3').chosen({ search_contains: true });      
});
```

Now, the practical problem is that, in a script I have already initialised 50 dropdowns but didn't made the `search_contains: true`.

Now I have to re-edit the code to make it enabled.

Is there any way if i can do this in a single code withot editing the code for 50 drop-downs?

May be something in the `chosen-library` itself.

But i would prefer not to tamper the chosen library.

Thanks

here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/288/

Comment: as your dropdown names are similar; simply use `'[id^=drp_menu]'` and proceed :)

Comment: @Saswat if you want assign it to all select box it code in fiddle will work

Answer (score 3):

dropdown elements are having id that start with `drp_menu`. you can use **[attribute start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to select them all and use chosen on them:

```
 $('[id^=drp_menu]').chosen({ search_contains: true });
```

### Working Demo

Comment: in the actual project, i have  (id)s with no resemblance to each other... like one id is (campaign_list) the other one is (user_timezone)

Comment: @Saswat: can you share how rendered html looks like??

Comment: Actual problem is its a company project, and the actual rendered html is quite a vast one...

Comment: they can at least have common parent or structure.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the contains selector will work:

```
$('[id*=drp_menu]').chosen({ search_contains: true });
```

Comment: better you check @Milind Anantwar answer . its a simple way to apply in only 1 line code

Comment: yes, the selector is much nicer in the answer you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your select this:

```
search_contains="true"
```

Example:

```
<select chosen class="form-control"
   search_contains="true"
   no-results-text="'Nenhum resultado encontrado para'"
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```